# Select all columns by a unique column value in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

In Rails 3, how do i select rows based on unique column values, i need to get all the columns for eg:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT date) FROM records
```

This only returns date column, but i want all the columns (name, date , age , created_at) columns not just the date.

Thanks for your help

Comment: But if two rows have the same date, which row do you want?

Comment: How are you actually running the query in the first place

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue here is that, by definition, there may be multiple records with the same date.  It requires logic in the user space to determine which of the multiple records with the unique date to use.  Here's some code to get those rows:

```
Record.select("distinct date").each do |record|
    records = Record.find_by_date record.date
    puts records.count # do something with the records
end
```

If what you're really after is uniqueness among multiple columns, list all the relevant columns in the distinct query:

```
Record.select("distinct date, name, age, created_at").each do |record|
    puts record.date
    puts record.name
    puts record.age
    puts record.created_at
    # ``record'' still represents multiple possible records
end
```

The fact that you are using distinct means that each "row" returned actually represents *n* rows, so the DB doesn't know which of the *n* rows to pull the remaining columns from.  That's why it only returns the columns used in distinct.  It can do no other...

Answer (score 5):

I think this will help you

```
Model.find(:all, :select => 'DISTINCT name, date, age, created_at')
```

Please use it and let me know.

Answer (score 4):

```
Model.group(:column)
```

For your case:

```
Record.group(:date)
```

This will return all your columns with no "date" repetitions.

Comment: column "<model>.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Answer (score 1):

For rails 3.2 and higher, `Model.select('DISTINCT name, date, age, created_at')`